# Кросплатформенная СУБД с возможностью переноса базы отсоединением/присоединением

Tags: база-данных

В *MSSQL* есть такая возможность, как перенести базу, просто отсоединив её, скопировав файл на другой компьютер и присоединив её.

А какие *СУБД* ещё позволяют подобный перенос (желательно работающие под *mac os*, помимо *linux*)?

*Oracle Database* и *MySQL* подобного не позволяют.

К тому же, необходимо, чтобы данная *СУБД* могла работать с базами размером от 10Гб.

Comment: Чем вызваны такие требования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MySQL подобного не позволяет

если используется «движок» myisam, то — позволяет. только под «отсоединением» следует понимать остановку демона `mysqld`.

наиболее быстро проделать эту процедуру одной командой можно примерно так:

```
$ sudo service mysql stop && \
 sudo chown root:root /var/lib/mysql/имя.базы.данных; \
 sudo service mysql start
```

а после этого каталог с базой данных `/var/lib/mysql/имя.базы.данных` можно копировать/перемещать на другую машину.

Answer (score 2):

Interbase/Firebird позволяют, во всяком случае если сервер был остановлен на момент переноса.

Answer (score 1):

> SQLite не является отдельно работающим процессом, с которым
>   взаимодействует программа, а предоставляет библиотеку

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite